# INTEGER() of a space character(s)

Tags: progress-4gl

Does anyone know why **INTEGER(" ")**  is zero in Progress 4GL?
The result is same even if you pass empty string to INTEGER() function. What could be the theory around this? Please help

I have gone through the documentation but couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the INTEGER() function does trimming of the input data.

This simple example shows signs of trimming:

```
DISPLAY INTEGER("1") = INTEGER("   1   ").
```

*Displays yes*

The spaces around the 1 is really not affecting the outcome of the conversion above leading me to think that INTEGER does trimming. Same result for:

```
DISPLAY INTEGER(" ") = INTEGER("").
```

I have no real idea as to why INTEGER("") returns 0 and not ? like for instance INTEGER("hello"). I guess it's just a matter of definition.

Comment: thanks @Jensd. Yeah, i observed that INTEGER() does trimming of the input data.

Answer (score 1):

"Why" is a religious question...

I believe that the 4GL is probably treating a blank string like it would an empty integer fill-in.  (Keep in mind that " " is equal to "" in the 4gl.)

Try this:

```
define variable i as integer no-undo.

i = 2.

update i.
```

Type a space bar.  Notice how the value goes to zero?

Comment: I think it's not religious but it's there for the blank when zero format which shows 0 as space.
`def var i as int form "zzz".
update i.`

Answer (score 0):

"" is a default value for character. If you define a char variable and do not specify INIT value, it will be "". 0 is a default value for integer. So INTEGER("") is very similar to integer with default initial value, which is 0.